# jquery - get src of image set by picturefill

Tags: jquery, image, responsive-design, src

I'm using [Scott Jehl's picturefill](https://github.com/scottjehl/picturefill) to serve up images responsively on my site.  My code looks like this:

```
<div data-picture id="front-image">
    <div data-src="image.jpg"></div>
    <div data-media="(min-width: 600px)" data-src="image-medium.jpg"></div>
    <div data-media="(min-width: 900px)" data-src="image-large.jpg"></div>
    <noscript><img src="image.jpg"></noscript>
</div>
```

After the page has been processed by Picturefill, the code looks like this:

```
<div data-picture="" id="front-image">
    <div data-src="image.jpg"></div>
    <div data-media="(min-width: 600px)" data-src="image-medium.jpg"></div>
    <div data-media="(min-width: 900px)" data-src="image-large.jpg"></div>
    <noscript><img src="image.jpg"></noscript>
    <img alt="" src="image-large.jpg">
</div>
```

Notice the new img tag at the end of the main div; that's the one generated by the script (and in this case since my browser window was large, it's the large image).

I'd like to grab the src of that image, but when I do something like

```
$(function() {
   var src = $('#front-image img').attr('src');
   // do other stuff with that variable once I have it
});
```

in a javascript file that is called after Picturefill, the var is empty.

My best guess is that the document is 'ready' and js evaluated *before* the Picturefill magic happens. How can I make my code wait until Picturefill has done its duty so I can grab the src from that img tag?

[Totally not a javascript person here so obviously if there's another way to go about getting the src or my guesses are completely wrong please correct me!]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing one of the first things @raminson suggested - splicing out a piece of the picturefill script (the part that uses matchmedia, in this case) and using it to figure out which image was correct to load for this screen size.

```
        $("#front-image div").each(function() {
            var media = $(this).attr( "data-media" );
                if( !media || (matchMedia &&matchMedia( media ).matches ) ){
                    var imgsrc = $(this).attr("data-src");
                    // do stuff with the img src
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

on option is using `DOMNodeInserted` event, which fires after insertion of a new `node` element.

```
$(document).on('DOMNodeInserted', function() {
   var src = $('#front-image > img').attr('src');
})
```

Comment: does that work in ie? google says that ie does not fire that event

Comment: @mkoryak yes, unfortunately this event only supported by modern browsers.

Comment: not to nitpick, but what if he inserts 100 other elements before inserting the image element he cares about?

Comment: Certainly not inserting 100 other elements, but I'm also getting an error that says " $("body").on is not a function" in FF11.

Comment: @Eileen it sounds that you are using an older version of jQuery in which `on` doesn't exist, you can replace `on` with `live`.

Comment: Hrm, even with live() this isn't working - I stuck an alert after the var declaration and it never popped -- perhaps picturefill uses some other method to insert the image?

Comment: @Eileen this event fires only in modern browsers and it's not related to how a new Node is inserted, try selecting document instead of body, it would be great if you post the codes that call picturefill.

Comment: You can look at the full text of picturefill here https://github.com/scottjehl/picturefill/blob/master/picturefill.js ; the part where it gets called is in all those eventListeners at the bottom. [For my purposes I don't care about grabbing a new src on resize and whatnot, just on initial page load.]

Answer (score 0):

Picturefill is awesome, but I was having some similar challenges with handling of the real images.

I ended up creating the [jquery.pikshur](https://github.com/geekytime/jquery.pikshur) plugin that does basically the same thing as picturefill, but gives you a bit more control over the elements, including allowing onLoad events for the images.